# Keep Unity from throwing build error about needing pro version to use specific feature I am not using

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**What I have found out so far**
I am using C# and Unity to make a simple game. When I try and build this game for Android I get this error:

```
Error building Player: SystemException: 'System.Net.Sockets' are supported only with Unity Android Pro. Referenced from assembly 'Mono.Data.Tds'.
```

What this is saying is that I need to buy the Android Pro Licence to build a game with `System.Net.Sockets` used in it. This confused me at first because I did not remember using `System.Net.Sockets` at all. After some research I discovered that `using` to broad of a scope in a Unity C# project causes this error, in my case I was doing:

```
using System;
```

Which by proxy included `System.Net.Sockets` making Unity think I was using it. 

 
**The Issue**
I am now using some open source library's in my game. When I went to build for Android after implementing these library's I got the same error. I then proceded to look at the source code for these library's and it seams that in every file the author(s) do:

```
using System;
```

Which was the cause of the error in the first part. These library's also do not make use of `System.Net.Sockets` but suffer from `using` to broad of a scope.

**The question**
Is there some way to have Unity recognize that I am not actually using `System.Net.Sockets` so it does not make me buy Android Pro?

**Edit**
After doing what @Roberto suggested I removed all my library's and then started adding them back in until I got the error. I have determined that [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is the culprit and is doing something with `System.Net.Sockets`. However when I search the source for '`System.Net.Sockets`' or `'Mono.Data.Tds`' there are no results.

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Mono.Data.Tds`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not right, adding `using System` **won't** expand to `System.Net.Sockets`. Doesn't make much sense and otherwise would make virtually every game impossible to run on Unity free.

The thing is your code or a plugin is using `System.Net.Sockets`. It may be a library (dll) perhaps, but definitely something is using it.

You can test my claims by creating a new project with one script with `using System` and see that you won't have problems; additionally you may want to create a new project and increasingly add the plugins you are using to check which one is using `System.Net.Sockets`.

---

I just read that this was happening on Unity 3.5.6. Are you using this version? If so, can't you update to Unity 4? I'm using Unity 4 and I don't have this problem. There's also 3.5.7 to try.

Comment: See edit to question. Added information on which library is causing this error.

Comment: Does this library use some dll? If its source doesn't use `Sockets` directly, it access via some assembly that you don't have access to. Do you have to use this library? If it's just to parse JSON you can use others, like MiniJson. However, if you are using the network part of Json.NET than there's nothing you can't do - it *has* to use `System.Net.Sockets`.

Comment: I am only using the JSON serialization and deserialization.

Comment: So just use another implementation - MiniJson is just one class, very simple, do everything I need.

Comment: with MiniJson how would I serialize or deserialize data from or to a Class?